# Error: Provided SSC API key is misconfigured

Tags: jss

I am getting this error while running `jss app` in `connected mode` any suggestions? I have checked the log but there wasn't anything relevant to this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The services used by JSS, such as the `Layout Service`, `GraphQL`, `Tracking Service`, and `Dictionary Service`, utilize the API Key mechanism provided by `Sitecore Services Client (SSC)`. You must create an API Key and note its Item ID for using it when connecting JSS apps to Sitecore.

It looks issue with API key configurations (`/sitecore/system/Settings/Services/API Keys/Key`). Here are a few suggestions to help troubleshoot:

1. Create a Sitecore API key if not already done. ([Create a Sitecore API key](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/211/sitecore-headless-development/create-a-sitecore-api-key.html))
2. Validate fields are configured on the API key.

   - `CORS Origins`: If you are using connected mode (quite likely), the APIs must support CORS so that your development server host, by default `http://localhost:3000`, is allowed to make HTTP requests to Headless Services. For local development, use `*` to allow all origins. In production, only allow specific origins. Specify multiple origins by separating them with a semicolon `;`
   - AllowedControllers: It is possible to use the asterisk `*` to allow all controllers, but explicitly whitelisting controllers is a best practice. If you use additional controllers, they must be added to this list.
3. Verify the `Sitecore Headless Services` module is working by visit the REST Layout Service endpoint at `<YourSitecoreInstance>/sitecore/api/layout/render?item=/&sc_apikey=<api_item_id>`.
4. Is your API Key item published? If your site is not using the `master` database, the API Key item needs to be published.
5. Ensure (again) that the API key value matches the API Key item ID in Sitecore. The default API Key resolver uses the API Key item ID as the key value.

Reference:

1. https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/211/sitecore-headless-development/create-a-sitecore-api-key.html
2. https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/211/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--connecting-a-jss-application-to-sitecore.html

Hope it helps!